# XML file in a Linux environment not showing the correct symbol

Tags: java, xml, linux

I am not sure if this is the correct place to post this or not.  I am trying to track down an error that does not show up in testing, but when the application is deployment.  Not sure if this part makes a difference or not, but when I compile on a Windows system using Netbeans IDE 8.0.2, there are 4 warnings about:

> “warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
>   warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
>   warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
>   4 warnings”

In the application there is a trigger when a certain value that is coming from a database, is show is supposed to print out to an XML file an infinity symbol.

```
outWriter.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?> \n");
char infinity2 = '\u221E';  //diplays ∞ in output file.
capPrinter += "<string>" +  infinity2 + "</string> \n"; //char test
```

The expected results in the XML file is correct in my testing on a Windows system, I also did several test on a Linux test environment, again had the same expected results.  On the production server, the application is only called once a month, and each time instead of printing the infinity symbol, the output is a question mark.  I am not sure what is wrong and what to do to correct this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You're most likely relying on the platform encoding, which is different in production than on the other platforms. Are you specifying the encoding when creating `outWriter`?

Comment: I'm not sure where *printing* comes into it, but it is conceivable that the problem is not in the program at all, but rather in whatever mechanism you are using to examine the results.